# Hadoop How to merge two nodes in to a cluster?

Tags: windows, hadoop

I have 2 PCs with windows 10 and set up a hadoop cluster on each according to https://exitcondition.com/install-hadoop-windows/ and was able to run the mapreduce wordcount example on each.

I would like two link both of them to create an actual cluster.

Followed the modifications from https://packetpushers.net/hadoop-for-network-engineers-part-2-adding-more-nodes/  but it didn't work

Comment: So both machines have their own namenode process?

Comment: Right now yes, but I'm stuck at configuring the SSH key. I edited the /etc/hosts file and each PC can ping the other. But PowerShell says ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub computername@username    does not exist. Will copying the keyname and keyname.pub files with a pendrive into the other PCs C:\Users\Username folder work?

Comment: I've not setup windows on Hadoop, but yes, you'd have to copy over ssh keys in some way into the authorized_keys file. You would also need to stop one of the Namenodes

Comment: Right now I'm trying to install it in WLS, all 3 machines ping each other. I created the ssh key with `hadoop@master:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa ` and then I try to copy it and get `hadoop@master:~$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@master` And the output is  `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host master port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable `

Comment: Based on that error, it doesn't appear there is an SSH server that is running on other machine